# Как правильно составить условие на проверку прав?

Tags: php

Добрый день!

Помогите составить условие. У пользователя есть два права: редактировать свои записи и редактировать все записи. Как будет правильно составить условие на проверку этих прав?

```
if (если разрешили редактировать свои записи) {
то выводим форму редактирования
}
elseif (разрешили редактировать все записи){
то разрешаем редактировать все записи
}
else {
перенаправление
}
```

У записи есть id и есть idUser, по которому проверяем, чья это запись.

Comment: @erkonov, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Ну так и делай:

```
<?
if(User.can('EDIT_ALL_POSTS')){
 // Даём редактировать все посты
}elseif(User.can('EDIT_THEIR_POSTS')){
 // Даём редактировать только свои посты
}else{
 // Посылаем нахрен
}
```

Надеюсь, понятно, что в методе `can` модели юзера проверяются разрешения.